# Twitter4j : Search for public tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

How does one search within public tweets using the Twitter4j library ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        try {
            Query query = new Query("Cocaine");
            QueryResult result;
            do {
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                    System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
                }
            } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

This gives me a `Authentication credentials are missing.` error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to register your app for Twitter. You can only do that if you have your own private account. After you obtain `ConsumerKey`, `ConsumerSecret`, `AccessToken` and `AccessTokenSecret` (they will be presented to you afret you register your application), the simplest solution is to change the code to the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("yourConsumeKey")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("yourConsumerSecret")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("yourAccessToken")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("yourTokenSecret");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        try {
            Query query = new Query("query");
            QueryResult result;
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
            }

            System.exit(0);
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
}
```

Comment: why serach for cocaine ?

Comment: I think you should ask that question to the guy who posted this question, not me. I copy-pasted the code and added some to make it work

Answer (score 3):

you need to register your application to get an OAuth Authentication Consumerkey, consumersecret and also Accesstoken and Accesstokensecret and provide these values to the configuration builder class.